# How to put first plot in the first row and the second one in the second row in a loop?

Tags: r, loops, plot

I want to have a page with two plots in a for loop in order to put my first output in c(`1`,`1`) and the next one in c(`2`,`1`). I use these commands:

```
f<-0
for (i in 1:m) {
   if ((i%%2!=0) { 
     f<-f+1
     Outfile<-paste(‘location,file name’,f,’.eps’)
     Par(mfrow=c(2,1)) 
   } else { 
     Outfile<-paste(‘location,file name’,f,’.eps’)
     Par(mfrow=c(2,1)) 
   } 
}
```

But the second plots will not go to the second column and each time it will only shows me the second plot not the first one, any suggestion?

Comment: I modified it. I will have 40 plots that i want to plot them in 20 pages. the first plots in the first row and the second one in the second row

Comment: You have called no functions that do any plotting.  Also, please make this reproducible by adding example data.

Comment: What do you mean by page?

Comment: in 20 different pages!

Comment: Ok...what kind of pages? a Pdf document? A Report?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if i understood the problem, but to show 10 plots in 5 rows and 2 columns, for example you can do:

```
op <- par(mfrow = c(5, 2), mar = c(0, 0, 0, 0), no.readonly = TRUE)

for (i in 1:10) {
    plot(rnorm(100))
}

par(op)
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this more or less what you are after?

```
x <- 1:10
#
y1 <- x
y2 <- 2 * x

m <- 40
#
for (i in 1:m) {
  if (i%%2 != 0) {
    png(sprintf("output-file-%d.png", ceiling(i / 2)))
    par(mfrow = c(1, 2))
    plot(x, y1)
  } else { 
    plot(x, y2)
    dev.off()
  } 
}
```